# How do I fix a WebView SSL Error Handler issue in kotlin so I can pass the Google play review

Tags: android, ssl, kotlin, android-security

I submitted a new App to Google play store and got a WebView SSL Error Handler alert and Google play review has prevented my app from going live. See Google's message from their help page below.

> 

To correct the issue, please update your apps code to invoke SslErrorHandler.proceed() whenever the certificate presented by the server meets your expectations, and invoke SslErrorHandler.cancel() otherwise. Please have the following points in mind while checking the validity of the certificate:

An app may be flagged if it does not contain sufficient checks for certificate validity; for instance, just checking the return value of getPrimaryError is not sufficient to establish the validity of the certificate.

It is not safe to ignore most SSL errors returned by SslError.getPrimaryError. Please note that  getPrimaryError returns the most severe error in a set of errors, so if getPrimaryError() != SSL_UNTRUSTED is true, the connection may still contain an SSL_UNTRUSTED error in the set of errors.

> 

I understand what Google is askng for but the problem is how to implement it in kotlin. I have checked through similar questions here on Stackoverflow and none of the suggested solutions have worked for me. I have implemented the solutions suggested but Google keeps rejecting it. I dont know if this could be because most of the solutions I have seen are from 2017 and before and may not be correct for current use.

I have implemented the onReceivedSslError for WebViewclient. I dont know what I am missing and would appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction as I am fairly new to kotlin. See below my sample code:

```
    private fun setWebClient() {
    webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
        override fun onProgressChanged(
            view: WebView,
            newProgress: Int
        ) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress)
            progressBar.progress = newProgress
            if (newProgress < MAX_PROGRESS && progressBar.visibility == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                progressBar.visibility = ProgressBar.VISIBLE
            }

            if (newProgress == MAX_PROGRESS) {
                progressBar.visibility = ProgressBar.GONE
            }
        }

        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onReceivedSslError(
            view: WebView?,
            handler: SslErrorHandler?,
            error: SslError?
        ) {
            super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error)
            handler?.cancel()
        }
    }
    }
}
```